# Add items according to the current fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

i have two fragments,a button a the ActionbBar and those two functions

```
public static int Pos1(){return 1;}

public static int Pos2(){return 2;}
```

(those are just example for functions)
when the button on the ActionBar clicked and im on fragment 1 i want to launch Pos1,and when the button on the ActionBar clicked and im on fragment 2 i want to launch Pos2.

i try to implement OnPageChangerListener and it still havnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

That was a dump question to ask...
took the ViewPager function GetCurrentItem and converted it to whati needed.